Dirrecionamiento indirecto Delta Designer
alguien sabe como dirrecionar indirectamente una variable en delta designer. Adjunto una prueba:
Este ejemplo funciona correctamente por lo que el valor que vaya tomando E0 será la dirreción de entrada del PLC -1,
Var1:= X0.0@E0;
Sin embargo mi objetivo es que también se pueda elegir la tarjeta de expansión es decir:
Que X0 pueda ser X0, X1, X2 dependiendo del valor que le pongamos en una variable he probado varias manera pero no lo consigo si alguien sabe como hacerlo se lo agradeceria.
Gracias de antemano.
